# Not being able to run bower in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, bower

Since yesterday I have been trying to install and use bower for managing my dependencies. After going through many articles although I have been able to install it. I am not being able to run it. Beside many articles I also followed this video:

[Bower running in Package Manager Console in Visual Studio install](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5B8LFF6AXs)

As the video is in some other languages even though I followed all the commonds, I could not get

```
$env:path
```

After doing everything when I type bower in the Package manager console, it gives me error

[image: Error while trying to install jquery]

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

PS: I have already installed npm and node.

Comment: Hey, if you ever figured this out please post answer. I'm stuck at the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use Bower correctly in Windows, you need to install `msysgit` correctly. This is the requirement as specified in bower github https://github.com/bower/bower#a-note-for-windows-users.

The option you have to select during installation is `Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt`.

After successful installation. Restart Visual Studio and then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after installing msysgit, I installed bower using:

**PM> Install-Package Bower**

Above step automatically installed dependencies (node.js, jquery)

I also had to specify relative path to bower.cmd:

**PM>.\MyProject.bin\bower.cmd install semantic-ui**