# bower support in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, requirejs, bower, angular-formly

I am trying to integrate angular-formly with visual studio 2012 and for that I did following steps:

**Problem**

Not able to integrate bower in Visual Studio **2012**

**So far approach taken**

1. downloaded node.js and install bower using install -g bower.
2. from the project directory I installed angular-formly packages via

   $ bower install angular api-check angular-formly --save
3. using requirejs I then plugged-in the generated .js files (inside bower_component folder) in my project.
4. I ran the project and I get following error.

   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined   (in formly.js)

**Questions:**

Is there some web plugin for Visual Studio 2012 to read and parse packages downloaded via bower.

I read some of the articles which suggests that bower support is provided VS-2013 onwards, does that mean in order to use bower I have to upgrade to VS-2013?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175463/not-being-able-to-run-bower-in-vs-2012

Answer (score 0):

Bower has been pretty much discontinued meaning you probably should not be using it and using npm instead